# One instance of Jenkins to call another

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I have Jenkins as the CI server. I have an automated testing tool setup on another machine. I installed Jenkins on the other machine also. Now I want one instance of Jenkins to trigger the project build on the other instance of Jenkins. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by pinging a build URL. i.e.

http://server-url:{port}/job/{job_name}/build

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to use the [Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Remote+Trigger+Plugin).  Calling the URL directly can be tricky if your build has parameters and / or your Jenkins instance is secured.